# Azure Synapse Serverles Pool Database Error: Cannot drop database "DataverseEnriched" because it is currently in use

Tags: azure-synapse

I am attempting to delete/drop a SQL Database created in from Azure Synapse Serverless Built-in Pool, but I keep on getting the error:

Error message: 'Failed to execute query. Error: Cannot drop database "" because it is currently in use. '. Tracking id: '3742517f-6b04-4b48-99e9-a1626d07ad8d'.

Any thoughts on why I'm getting error, and how to drop the database?

Now, when issue the following code:

```
USE [master];  
GO  
DROP  DATABASE [DataverseEnriched]; 
GO
```

I get the following output

[image]

Comment: `USE [master]; 
GO 
DROP  DATABASE [Db1];
GO`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Use Master in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and run below command on Azure UI portal.
DROP DATABASE [Database Name]
GO

Answer (score 0):

> [Azure Synapse Serverles Pool Database Error: Cannot drop database "DataverseEnriched" because it is currently in use]

- I repro'd the same error in Serverless SQL pool. I created Database called `Db1` and tried to drop database.

> Failed to execute query. Error: Cannot drop database "Db1" because it is currently in use.

[image]

- In order to drop database, use master. Below is the script.

```sql
USE [master];
GO 
DROP  DATABASE [Db1];
GO
```

Comment: Hi @Aswin, thanks for reaching out. I tried your suggestion, however unfortunately I got the error ```A fatal scripting error occurred.
Incorrect syntax was encountered while parsing GO.```

Comment: Could you share the screenshot of script and error message?

Comment: Hi @Aswin, I'm now getting the output Cannot drop database "DataverseEnriched" because it is currently in use.
I have updated the question showing the code producing the output

Comment: Are you giving  `GO` in the new line?

Comment: I am giving GO, in the exact way you showed me.. see updated question

Comment: Okay.. Are you not getting this error `A fatal scripting error occurred. Incorrect syntax was encountered while parsing GO.`? now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250556/discussion-between-aswin-and-patterson).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying it from the Synapose studio ?

```
--- Create the DB 
CREATE DATABASE TESTDB1
-- Run the below query and it will fails as the 
-- DB is already there 
CREATE DATABASE TESTDB1
---Error 
-- 12:22:47 PM
-- Started executing query at Line 5
-- Database 'TESTDB1' already exists.
 --  Choose a different database name.
-- Total execution time: 00:00:00.376
use master
go 
DROP DATABASE TESTDB1
-- Works fine 
-- Started executing query at Line 12
-- Changed database context to 'master'.
-- (0 record affected)

-- (0 record affected)

-- Total execution time: 00:00:00.401
```

Screenshot if that helps .

[image]